# A quotient of tensor algebra of $V \otimes k$

Tags: tensor-products, algebras

Let $k$ be a field and $V$ a $k$-vector space. Denote the inclusion of $k$ in $k \oplus V$ by $m$. A book that I'm consulting *(Ramanan's Global Calculus)* asks the reader to prove that the quotient of the tensor algebra of $k \oplus V$ by the 2-sided ideal generated by $1-m(1)$ is canonically isomorphic to the tensor algebra of $V$. I'm not quite sure how to do this.

There is a natural map from $k \oplus V \to V$. This induces a map between the respective tensor algebras, but the kernel of this map seems to be generated by $m(1)$ and not $1 - m(1)$. I'm not quite sure how to construct a map whose kernel is as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: if $T(V)$ is the tensor algebra on $V$, define $f: k \oplus V \to T(V)$ by $f(x, v) = x + v$ (where I am identifying $k$ and $v$ with their images in $T(V)$ expressed as the sum  $k \oplus V \oplus V^{{\otimes}2} \oplus \ldots$). Then $f$ induces an algebra homomorphism $T(k \oplus V) \to T(V)$ by the [universal property of the tensor algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra).